# How to add longer "item_name" using a Paypal form?

Tags: paypal

I'm creating a webpage for a client where the user can select multiple options for an item, and then send that information directly to Paypal with a Buy Now button.

Everything works but I can't put a description longer than 125 characters it seems (in the item_name field).

any ideas on how to send all the info onto paypal? ( I would need around 250 chars )

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"**item_name**" value can only be 127 Character Length, however you can also pass the variable "**item_number**" (127 Character Length) to track product or service purchased (this value is also visible to buyers).

Example:

```
<input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="T-shirt AB Black">
<input type="hidden" name="item_number" value="APB9823400f">
```

Ref. https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/paypal-payments-standard/integration-guide/Appx_websitestandard_htmlvariables/

And for *internal reference*, you can also pass "**custom**" variable (256 Character Length), Pass-through variable for your own tracking purposes, which *buyers do not see*.

In alternative, you might consider "**Add to Cart**" buttons with **Upload command**, you can find instructions and examples here: https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/paypal-payments-standard/integration-guide/cart_upload/

Comment: This is a great comprehensive answer Federica, thanks for your time! :)